# Batch scripting-cleanup script

Tags: windows, batch-file

i've engaged with work in batch script.these things i need to do
1.i want to find the folder say like "name" in particular directory
ex:
c:\test\name
c:\test\b\name
c:\test\n\c\name
2.in the name folder, need to delete all sub folders and files and all which is more than 90 days.

i have changed my question now please give me an idea...

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an asterisk `*` so that the folder set expands to all subdirectories of the `_delete` folder. Also, the `/D /R` construct seems unnecessary on second thought, because `RD /S` does already take care of deleting **directories** recursively.

```
FOR /D %%A IN ( folder_you_want_to_clean\* ) DO IF EXIST "%%A" RD /S /Q "%%A"
```

But it won't delete the **files** in the `folder_you_want_to_clean` folder itself, though. Do that with the `DEL` command - the `/Q` option suppresses the confirmation prompt, just like with the `RD` command:

```
DEL /Q folder_you_want_to_clean\*
```

---

**Concrete example:** Suppose the folder you want to clean is `C:\data\oldstuff`. Then just do:

```
FOR /D %%A IN ( C:\data\oldstuff\* ) DO IF EXIST "%%A" RD /S /Q "%%A"
```

All **directories** contained in `C:\data\oldstuff` will be gone (and of course, any files in those directories). But any **files** in `C:\data\oldstuff` itself will still be there! So to delete those as well, do:

```
DEL /Q C:\data\oldstuff\*
```

Comment: FOR /R /D "local drive path" %%A IN ( _delete\* ) DO IF EXIST "%%A" RD "%%A" /S /Q-   _delete\* showing incorrect syntax..

Comment: @samun: It seems like `/R /D` is in fact invalid and needs to be written as `/D /R` - corrected. I'm quite amazed by that.

Comment: my concern is recursively find the root folder and and delete the sub directories and files and all...

Comment: @samun: Yes, it does do that, I've tried it. I just rewrote the command by hand in here and mixed up the order of `/R` and `/D` while doing so...

Comment: @samun: The requirement to check for *file ages* substantially changes the problem. Have a look at [`FORFILES`](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html).

Comment: hi..i tried with this code but it's deleting the root folder also FOR /D /r "C:\Hai\90" %%A IN ( _delete\ ) DO IF EXIST "%%A" RD /S /Q "%%A"

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "targetdir=U:\destdir"
ECHO(DEL "%targetdir%\*?*"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /ad "%targetdir%\*" '
  ) DO (
 ECHO(RD /S /Q "%%~a"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `targetdir` to suit your circumstances. It could of course be replaced by a literal if you wish.

The required RD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(RD` to `RD` to actually delete the directories.

The required DEL commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(DEL` to `DEL` to actually delete the files.

the `del` and `for` commands could be cascaded with a `&` if required. The `for` is spread across a nuber of lines for clarity.